# Log Snowpark pushdown queries in scala

Tags: scala, logging, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using Snowpark to connect to snowflake & perform operations on snowflake data, codebase is in scala.

Is there any way to log pushdown queries.

Comment: By default Converted SQL queries are logged to log files if we persist or route Java command logs to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several ways to do this:

- use the Snowflake UI and look at the **Activity -> Query History**
- use [explain](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/scala/troubleshooting#viewing-the-execution-plan-for-a-query-in-snowpark) method on the DataFrame
- enable debug logging in Snowpark and check the log

Comment: How to enable debug logging in Snowpark?

Comment: Logging is documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/scala/troubleshooting#changing-the-logging-settings)